# How to add watermark to every page of a PDF in php (laravel)?

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, watermark

I am adding watermarks to every page of a PDF in Laravel, but I just got only a watermark on the first page.

How do I loop over all of the pages?

Here is my current code:

```
 if ($request->input('ref_person')== '1') {
            $ref_person = SiteHelper::get_applicant_ref_person($cv_no->cv_no);
            $html .= '<h3>Reference Person</h3>
<div class="line" style="border-bottom: 2px solid #7dc24b;"></div>
<table  cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">';
            foreach ($ref_person as $ref) {
                $html .=
                    '<tr nobr="true">
    <td style="float:left">'. $ref->reference_person_name . '
    </td>
    <td style="float:left"><b>'. $ref->reference_person_position . '</b>
   </td>
    <td style="float:left">
  <b>" ' . $ref->reference_person_company . ' "</b>
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr nobr="true">
    <td colspan="2"><b>Mobile No : </b>' . @$ref->reference_person_mobile . '
    </td>
    <td style="float:left">'. $ref->reference_person_email . '
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td style="float:left"></td>
 </tr>';
            }
$pdf->SetLineWidth(2);

// set alpha to semi-transparency
            $pdf->SetAlpha(0.2);

// draw jpeg image
            $pdf->Image(public_path('img/water.png'), 150, 160, 150, 150, '', '#', '', true, 72);

// restore full opacity
        $pdf->SetAlpha(1);
```

Comment: What is `$pdf`? We'll need more information to help.